# c# linq one to many filter by child property

Tags: c#, linq, properties, one-to-many

I have a product model class with many versions childs:

```
public class Product {
  public int Id {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string Name {
    get;
    set;
  } = "";
  public List <Version> Versions {
    get;
    set;
  } = new List <Version> ();
}

public class Version {
  public int Id {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string Name {
    get;
    set;
  } = "";
  public DateTime ReleaseDate {
    get;
    set;
  } = new DateTime();
}
```

I want to filter by a child property: releasedate:

```
var releaseDateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact("20110720", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      
    var products = ProductRepository.GetAll();
    List <ProductDto> list;
    list = products.Where(
      p => (p.Name!.StartsWith("p") &&
        p.Name!.Length > 0) &&
        GetReleaseDateFromVersion(p.Versions.OrderBy(p => p.ReleaseDate).LastOrDefault()) > releaseDateFrom
    ).Select(p =>
      new ProductDto {
        Id = p.Id,
          Name = p.Name,
          LatestVersionDate = GetReleaseDateFromVersion(p.Versions.OrderBy(p => p.ReleaseDate).LastOrDefault())
      }).ToList();
      
    DateTime GetReleaseDateFromVersion(Version v) => v == null ? new DateTime() : v.ReleaseDate;
    
    list.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", p.Name, p.LatestVersionDate));
```

The result output shows that the filter date > 20 July 2022 does not work:

```
product 1 11/20/2013 00:00:00
product 2 06/20/2013 00:00:00
```

Product 2 should not be listed.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions how to fix this query?

The code can be run here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/esRdOg

**Edit after comment from @SergeySosunov**

As @SergeySosunov correctly noted: My filter date was wrong. The above code works as expected.

Comment: Can I ask where you have `20 July 2022` in your code? I see only "20110720" which is 2011, and the products 1 and 2 in your output are 2013... And 2013 is > 2011.. Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: Wrong order : GetReleaseDateFromVersion(p.Versions.Where(x => x.ReleaseDate >  releaseDateFrom). OrderBy(p => p.ReleaseDate).LastOrDefault()

Comment: @SergeySosunov You are correct. My filter date is wrong. With the correct date it works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: filter + orderBy vs orderBy + filter will not make a difference for the result, but it is a bit more effective in terms of cpu and memory to filter data you dont need and apply sorting function after. n records orderBy + n records filter vs n records filter + n-x records orderBy, but anyway.